# Function information in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I'd like to know if there's a way to view ANSI C function information in Visual Studio. I'm working with C and I don't like having to go to external websites for viewing function's return values or what it does.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS 2012 so I'm not sure if it works in 2010 but if you put your cursor on the function and hit the F12 key it takes you to the declaration of the function or method which  shows the return value, arguments and a description.

Comment: Thanks, for me it's driving me to the header of the function in the .h files. It's the same as pressing CTRL and click in the function. It says what type the function is, but sadly it doesn't have the description.